# window.open não está funcionando após a execução do Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de compartilhamento de URL salvando em banco de dados toda vez em que é clicado em uma das redes sociais do site.

Acontece que o `window.open` que uso para acessar a rede social não está funcionando após a chamada do Ajax.

Alguém faz ideia o porque isso acontece?

Um exemplo do link de compartilhamento:

```
teste.com.br/teste?c=xyoz&cc=1
```

o `cc=1` é o `lastInsertId();` quando grava o compartilhamento.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo rawurlencode($url."&c=cd3a0725fa81899"); ?>" class="popup" title="Compartilhe com Facebook" rede-social="facebook">
  <span class="icon">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="18px" height="18px" viewBox="0 0 28 28" enable-background="new 0 0 28 28" xml:space="preserve">
      <path d="M27.825,4.783c0-2.427-2.182-4.608-4.608-4.608H4.783c-2.422,0-4.608,2.182-4.608,4.608v18.434
            c0,2.427,2.181,4.608,4.608,4.608H14V17.379h-3.379v-4.608H14v-1.795c0-3.089,2.335-5.885,5.192-5.885h3.718v4.608h-3.726
            c-0.408,0-0.884,0.492-0.884,1.236v1.836h4.609v4.608h-4.609v10.446h4.916c2.422,0,4.608-2.188,4.608-4.608V4.783z" />
    </svg>
  </span>
  <span class="text">Facebook</span>
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.rrssb-buttons li a').click(function(){
  var url        = "ajax/salvarCompartilhamento.php";
  var redesocial = $(this).attr('rede-social');
  $.ajax({
    type:  'post',
    data:  {
            'rede_social' : redesocial,
           },
    url:   url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout:  120000,
    async:false,
    success: function(link){
      if(link != 'erro'){
        sucesso = true;
      }
    }
  });
  if(sucesso){
    var t = 600;
    var i = 450;
    var h = ($(window).width()-t)/2;
    var n = ($(window).height()-i)/2;
    var o = $(this).attr('href') + link;
    var w = "status=1,width="+t+",height="+i+",top="+n+",left="+h;
    window.open(o,"share",w);
  }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
include_once '../includes/constantes.php';
include_once __CLASS_FOLDER__.'/Teste.class.php';

if(!empty($_POST)){
  $dados = $_POST;
} else if(!empty($_GET)) {
  $dados = $_GET;
} else {
  die('Acesso não autorizado');
}

$teste = new Teste();
$salvado = $teste->salvarCompartilhamento($dados);

if(is_numeric($salvado)){
  echo "&ss=$salvado";
} else {
  echo 'erro';
}
```

Comment: Tem noção do que uma chamada assíncrona, que é o AJAX, significa na prática?

Comment: Sim, na pratica, o if seria executado antes do termino do ajax. Mas a flag async:false nao desabilitaria isso?